# xrdp immediately terminated session

Tags: lxde, remmina

I'm trying to connect via remmina, to a vagrant machine with lxde and xrdp.

A grey screen is shown for 5 seconds then session is terminated. Here is /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log log:

```
[20171026-12:41:30] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20171026-12:41:30] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username vagrant, ip 192.168.10.10:48666 - socket: 7
[20171026-12:41:30] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20171026-12:41:30] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=3066 - wmpid=3065
[20171026-12:41:35] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username vagrant, display :10.0, session_pid 3061, ip 192.168.10.10:48666 - socket: 7
```

Here is also ~/.xsession-error log:

```
Xsession: X session started for  at Thu Oct 26 13:05:47 CEST 2017
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
Value in failed request:  0x5
Serial number of failed request:  6
Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:vagrant being added to access control list
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, and I followed these instructions from https://askubuntu.com/questions/234856/unable-to-do-remote-desktop-using-xrdp

- install xrdp which uses the remote desktop protocol to present a GUI to the user. 
  It can provide a fully functional Linux terminal server, capable of accepting connections 
  from rdesktop, freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients. 
  xrdp is the daemon that handles RDP remote desktop access from Windows machines to Linux
- edit the "/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini" file to include the line:
  address=0.0.0.0
  right under #background=626x72 line. 0.0.0.0 is the local server address of xrdp
- Restart xrdp service
- allow xrdp port (probably 3389) through firewall
- Install xfce4 desktop environment an update to xfce, minimalistic faster and lightweight
  sudo apt-get install xfce4
- sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal : way better than xterm
- sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full tango-icon-theme : installs icon sets
- Now we modify 2 files to make sure xrdp uses xfce4

  - echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
  - secondly we modify startup file for xRDP located at /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
    so it will start xfce4. Replace the last line with 
    startxfce4 
    (before it had something which started with a ., but no matter whatever it is, just 
    replace the last line)
  - restart xrdp service: sudo service xrdp restart
- Now you are ready to log into the computer from client using Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe). 
  Just supply the ipv4 or hostname of the VNC server.

Comment: I think the part that really got it to work was the second to last step where you modify those 2 files. The gui once remoted in is a lot different than the standard gnome desktop, so I think that has to do with installingt the xfce4 and gnome icons